# CSS/JS disable animation

Tags: javascript, css

How can I enable/disable an animation from inline CSS

```
.loading-bar {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* transform: rotate(0deg) skew(15deg); */
  /* -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skew(15deg); */
  /* animation: loading 1s ease-in-out infinite; */
}
```

Actually, I came up with this function which works, but rely on CSS index that I had to put it 0 for using `document.styleSheets[0].rules`

```
function ani(x) {
  var el;
  if (document.styleSheets[0].rules)
    el = document.styleSheets[0].rules[0];
  else if (document.styleSheets[0].cssRules)
    el = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0];
  el.style.animation = (x ? 'loading 1s ease-in-out infinite' : '');
}
```

There is a more elegant way?
Thank you.

Comment: Use a class which fires just the animation and toggle the class via js `.classList.toggle()`

Comment: Use `classList.add`, `classList.remove` or `classList.toggle` to wrap between the classes  https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/4730201

Comment: read this: https://alligator.io/js/classlist/